# Retrieving a method by using string of method's name? Python

Tags: python

I'm wondering if it's possible in Python to find a method in a different function by using it's string name.

In one function, I pass in a method:

```
def register(methods):
    for m in methods:
        messageType = m.__name__
        python_client_socket.send(messageType)


register(Foo)
```

In a different method that takes in the string that was sent over, I want to be able to associate a number with the method in a dictionary ( i.e. `methodDict = {1: Foo, 2:Bar, etc...}` )

Is there a way in Python to find the method from the string?

Answer (score 6):

If you're *certain* of the method name (do **not** use this with arbitrary input):

```
getattr(someobj, methodDict[someval])
```

Answer (score 3):

This accomplishes that type of "if it's defined use it, otherwise let the user know it's not ready yet" feel.

```
if hasattr(self, method):
  getattr(self, method)()
else:
  print 'No method %s.' % method
```

Answer (score 1):

Although other answers are correct that `getattr` is the way to get a method from a string, if you're prepopulating a dictionary with method names don't forget that methods themselves are first-class objects in Python and can equally well be stored in dictionaries, from where they can be called directly:

```
methodDict[number]()
```

Answer (score 0):

`globals()` will return a dictionary of all local-ish methods and other variables. To launch a known method from a string you could do:

```
known_method_string = 'foo'
globals()[known_method_string]()
```

Edit: If you're calling this from a object perspective, `getattr(...)` is probably better.

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick for what was needed for now. Might need getattr later, but the globals() got me going :)

Answer (score 0):

```
method = getattr(someobj, method_name, None)
if method is None:
    # complain
    pass
else:
    someobj.method(arg0, arg1, ...)
```

If you are doing something like processing an XML stream, you could bypass the `getattr` and have a dictionary mapping tags to methods directly.